# Pagination in subscription

Tags: pagination, fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have an operator that performs subscriptions for specific types of orion entities. 
However, although i use the relevant field (limit) in the options object i push for the subscription, data still arrive paginated at 20 elements (I would like to increase it). Is pagination (limit) option valid only for query operations, or is it available for subscriptions as well?

Here is my code:

```
var subscribe = function subscribe() {
    this.connection = new NGSI.Connection(this.ngsi_server, {
        ngsi_proxy_url: this.ngsi_proxy
    });

    var attributeList = null;
    var duration = this.subscriptionUpdateRate;
    var throttling = null;
    var notifyConditions = [{
            'type': 'ONCHANGE',
            'condValues': this.condValues
        }];
    var options = {
        flat: true,
        limit: 999,
        onNotify: function(data) {
            handlerReceiveEntity(data);
        },
        onSuccess: function(data) {
            ....
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
                this.connection.cancelSubscription(this.subscriptionID);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this)
    };
    this.connection.createSubscription([this.entities], attributeList, duration, throttling, notifyConditions, options);
};
```

Still, I am getting only 20 entities instead of ~40 when the function is first invoked. Any idea what might be wrong?

The version of Orion is 0.14.0.

Comment: Can you provide us what version or instance of the Orion Context Broker are you using? I think this will be very useful for detecting if this is related with bugs or with new features of the Orion Context Broker. Thanks :)

Comment: I just updated the main question text to reflect it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the Orion Context Broker doesn't allow the use of the limit/offset parameters in subscriptions, it usage is limited to the query operations. Moreover, I have never see paginated notifications. Anyway, if this is a change in the Orion Context Broker API, please create a ticket in the [WireCloud's issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues).

See [Orion Context Broker - User and Programmers Guide](http://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide) for more info, but I don't see any relevant change that can explain this behaviour.

Comment: You are right, this might be an issue of orion in the first place. I will let them know and if it gets implemented i will create a relevant ticket for wirecloud as well.

Comment: @Artem, probably this involves an issue at Orion (not sure if a bug, but al least something that needs to be analyzed). Could you report the problem at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/new, please? Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan I most certainly will :-)

Comment: Issue URL (for reference): https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/591